# Динамическая подгрузка DLL

Tags: c#, dll

Допустим, у меня есть метод:

```
private void UnZip(string FileName, string Path)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(FileName))
    {
        zip.ExtractAll(Path, ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
        zip.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Он содержится в `using Ionic.Zip`. Как мне, не указывая его в `Reference`, использовать классы и методы, подгружая динамически.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\DotNetZip.dll");
Type classType = a.GetType("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile");
object CreateInst = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod("ExtractAll");
```

Comment: Ну, начало положено, что дальше не получается?

Comment: @Андрей Ругается, при попытке считать метод и непонятно как работать со считанными классами и методами.

Comment: @Идентикон: как именно ругается?

Comment: @VladD `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: "Обнаружено неоднозначное соответствие."` Я так понимаю это из-за того, что там 2 метода с одинаковым именем.

Comment: @Идентикон: Угу. Нужно использовать другую перегрузку GetMethod, в которой указываются типы аргументов.

Comment: `Type fileActionType = a.GetType("Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction"); MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod("ExtractAll", new[] { typeof(string), fileActionType });` Как-то так пробуйте

Comment: С другой стороны, может вам просто использовать `Событие AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` и не мучиться с рефлексией?

Comment: @Андрей Хочу с этим до разобраться, а так  придется еще разбираться с `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`.

Comment: Это проще, добавил ответ

Comment: @Андрей Я делаю просто в классе установщика, мне кажется, что через событие там не получится. Мне просто нужно, чтобы при установки подключалась динамически dll и распаковывался файл при установке.

Comment: Получится, попробуйте. Можно даже не извлекать библиотеку в файл, а извлечь из ресурсов как массив байт и воспользоваться методом `Assembly.Load()`

Comment: Дополнил ответ с использованием рефлексии

Comment: @Идентикон ваше понятие "динамического" подключения ничем, по сути, не отличается от обычного Add Reference. Вариант через событие вообще отличается от Add Reference только тем, что можно указать путь к сборке (или загрузить ее из ресурсов) - т.к. событие вызовется ровно в тот момент, когда рантайм при "статическом" подключении полезет эту сборку искать рядом на диске. Может вам проще референс добавить?

Comment: @PashaPash При сборке в `dll`l у меня ссылки не компоновались в 1 файл, а просто копировались, рядом с моей. При подключении в setup wizard библиотеки не подтягивались.

Comment: @Идентикон они и не должны копироваться. просто? imho, стоило сначала выянить, почему сборки не подключаются из того места, куда их setup положил (через fusion log viewer). И потом уже чинить хитрой подгрузкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я предлагаю вам не мучиться с рефлексией, а воспользоваться [событием `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx):

Просто подпишитесь на него в точке входа в приложение:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    ...
```

И в обработчике загрузите нужную сборку:

```
private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name == "DotNetZip, Version=1.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6583c7c814667745")
        return Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\DotNetZip.dll");
    return null;
}
```

Обратите внимание, это необычное событие - оно имеет возвращаемое значение. Мы должны загрузить нужную сборку и вернуть её. При возврате `null` будет инициировано исключение.

Всё. Метод будет работать в его первозданном виде:

```
private void UnZip(string FileName, string Path)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(FileName))
    {
        zip.ExtractAll(Path, ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
        //zip.Dispose(); это не нужно тут
    }
}
```

---

Если вы всё же намерены действовать через рефлексию, у меня работает такой вариант:

```
private static void UnZip(string FileName, string Path)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\DotNetZip.dll");
    Type classType = a.GetType("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile");
    object inst = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new object[] { FileName });
    Type fileActionType = a.GetType("Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction");
    object doNotOverwrite = Enum.ToObject(fileActionType, 2);
    MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod("ExtractAll", new[] { typeof(string), fileActionType });
    method.Invoke(inst, new object[] { Path, doNotOverwrite });
    MethodInfo disposeMethod = classType.GetMethod("Dispose");
    disposeMethod.Invoke(inst, new object[0]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, надо будет еще попробовать через событие. С рефлексией разобрался.

Comment: Попробуйте обязательно, это гораздо проще